# Facebook sdk 3.9 file is not found

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, xcode5, armv7

I integrated the `facebook sdk 3.9.pkg` in my application & I cant able to run the app in the `simulator` or in the `device`.I changed all the setting according to the `ios7` but it is still showing as file is not found.I am using the xcode version xcode 5.0.1 .I cant able to run the app.Waiting for your answer.

Comment: where you are adding the package???

Comment: i was downloaded that pkg file and took facebook framework into the application.

Comment: which file  in your app not found ?

Comment: sdk is sucessfully installed and application is running in device now but it is not opening in the ios 7

Answer (score 1):

I have suggested you to use a different Facebook SDK open this Blog this is very simple :-

http://preetlotey999.blogspot.in/2013/11/log-in-with-facebook-share-application.html

In this code you can only write a simple one line code in your button's action & you can automatically log in through Facebook & share the application also.